# Prove or disprove: The set $V=\{(p,q) |p,q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I do not understand this question and I am not very familiar with the techniques.

How would one go about answering this?

Comment: I suppose you are asking this question in the context of vector spaces/subspaces?

Comment: The traditional subspace test. Is $0$ vector in the set? If you add two of those vectors, do you get a third? If you multiply one of those vectors by *any* scalar, do you get one in that set?

Comment: @Wojowu Yes I am.

Comment: Over what field?

Comment: @AhmedHussein field?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say he means a *real* vector subspace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're using a book that has not introduced the term "field", this is probably what your definition of a *subspace* is:

> A set $V \subset W$ for some vector space $W$ is called a *subspace* of $W$ if:
>
> - for any $x,y \in V$, $x + y$ is also in $V$
> - **for any** $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ and any $x \in V$, $\alpha x$ is also in $V$

With this definition, we can see that your set $V$ is **not** a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$.  To see why, consider the element $x = (1,1) \in V$, and take $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$.  Then, we see that although $x$ is an element in $V$,
$$
\alpha x = \sqrt{2}(1,1) = (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})
$$
is a vector that does **not** have rational entries, so it is **not** an element of $V$.  So, $V$ is not a *subspace* of $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 4):

One usual requirement
is,
if
$a \in V$
and
$c \in \mathbb{R}$,
then
$ca \in V$.

This is not true
if $c$ is irrational.

If we restrict 
the multipliers
in the definition of subspace
to rationals,
which I guess we could call
a rational subspace,
this seems true.